# Styles of items in Task list in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, sharepoint, client-side, sharepoint-2013, frontend

I have problem with client side in Task list in Sharepoint 2013. I need to distinguish maintask (set the background color for example). I tried to change styles ".ms-listviewtable .ms-itmhover" and ".ms-alternating" in core15v.css, but did not get the expected result. How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to leave core15 as is OOTB and add a new stylesheet with your overwrites. Make sure this new stylesheet is called after core15 in the masterpage and use the inspector in your browser to make sure you're getting the entire selector. If you write new properties for `.ms-listviewtable` but core15 uses `#s4-workspace .ms-listviewtable`, the one defined in core15 will take precedence as a more specific selector.